# How do I find the next power of 2 for a u64 integer in Rust efficiently?

Tags: rust

I am searching for a fast way to find the next power of two for a 64-bit integer in Rust. For example, if I have 23 the result must be 32. I tried this code:

```
fn ceil_pow2(x: u64) -> u64 {
    let mut y: u64 = x;
    let mut z: u64 = 1;
    while y > 0 {
        y >>= 1;
        z <<= 1;
    }
    if z == 2 * x {
        z >>= 1;
    }
    z
}
```

If gives correct results but the code does not look efficient and I believe there is a faster way to implement. Could anyone help? `Asm` code inside a Rust function is welcomed if it gains performance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This function already exists in the standard library as [`u64::next_power_of_two`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u64.html#method.next_power_of_two):

> Returns the smallest power of two greater than or equal to `self`.

```
fn ceil_pow2(x: u64) -> u64 {
    x.next_power_of_two()
}
```

---

If you're curious, its current implementation is roughly equal to:

```
fn next_power_of_two(n: u64) -> u64 {
    if n <= 1 {
        1
    } else {
        (u64::MAX >> (n - 1).leading_zeros()) + 1
    }
}
```

Comment: And the implementation of `leading_zeros()` is what? I suspect there has to be a loop somewhere.

Comment: @thebusybee It's implemented via the [`ctlz` intrinsic](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/intrinsics/fn.ctlz.html) which uses the corresponding [LLVM intrinsic](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#llvm-ctlz-intrinsic) that will in turn use CPU instructions where available - see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_first_set) for details.

Comment: @thebusybee No loops required! This technically depends on the target ISA (x86, ARM, etc.), but this operation is common enough that most have a `clz` (count-leading-zeros) or `ffs` (find-first-set) instruction that does this in hardware: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_first_set)